In ListBuilder, UUID sometimes shown for anonymous
I created a custom entity using drush generate entity:content.
In MyEntityListBuilder.php:
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity): array {
    $row = [];
    $row['id'] = $entity->id();
    $row['label'] = $entity->toLink();
    /** @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user_entity */
    $user_entity = $entity->get('uid')->entity;
    $username_options = [
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'settings' => ['link' => $user_entity->isAuthenticated()],
    ];
    $row['uid']['data'] = $entity->get('uid')->view($username_options);
    $row['created']['data'] = $entity->get('created')->view(['label' => 'hidden']);
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

However, when I view the list on different servers, I'm seeing different behavior.
On ddev, when I go to admin/content/my-entity, for entities created by the anonymous user, I see Anonymous as the author.
However, on a platform.sh server, for entities created by the anonymous user, I see the UUID of the anonymous user as the author.
Why am I seeing this difference in the display?  As far as I can tell, the code and database of both sites is exactly the same (I am importing the same database on both).
